# CustomClass copy error: AttributeError: 'CustomClass' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following class in its own .py file:

```
import pandas as pd

class CashFlowSchedule(object):
    flows = {}
    annual_growth_rate = None
    df = None

    def __init__(self, daterange, months=range(1, 13), amount=0, growth=0, growth_month=1):

        self.annual_growth_rate = growth

        for dt in daterange:

            if dt.month == growth_month:
                amount *= (1. + self.annual_growth_rate)


            if dt.month in months:
                self.flows[dt] = amount
            else:
                self.flows[dt] = 0.

        self.df = pd.DataFrame([self.flows]).T
```

When I call:

```
import cf_schedule as cfs
x=cfs.CashFlowSchedule(pd.date_range('20180101','20190101'))
x.copy()
```

I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-c96b6d8d0ab0> in <module>()
----> 1 x.copy()

AttributeError: 'CashFlowSchedule' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

What is going wrong, and what am I missing here?

This class is exceptionally primitive, and I thought `__copy__` should exist in the `object` methods.

Thank you

Comment: To call .copy() on csf, or CashFlowSchedule, you would need to define a method called copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the class `CashFlowSchedule` does not have a `copy()` method.

Assuming you want to create a copy of `CashFlowSchedule`, you should use Python's `copy` [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).

To create a shallow copy:

```
import copy
import cf_schedule as cfs
x=cfs.CashFlowSchedule(pd.date_range('20180101','20190101'))
x_copy = copy.copy(x)
```

To create a deep copy, just replace the last line with this:

```
x_copy = copy.deepcopy(x)
```